# Layered navigation, going to other page doesnt work

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, category, layered-navigation, pagination

I've done an upgrade on a Magento webshop and on the upgraded theme (Joomlart) I've got a problem with the layered navigation in combination with pagination. Was working before I did and upgrade. (Magento theme upgraded from 1.4.3.2 to 1.7)

I've recreated the problem with the theme template;

http://1d963b0e2ceac64a.builder.joomlart.com/pcgames/classic.html

(Updated site is still on staging server.)

Using the grid view, 9 articles.

The category has 41 products.

When I use shop by -> price ($0.00 - $999.99) (39 products) this generates the following slug: "/category/slug.html?price=-1000"

All good so far.

But if I want to see the following nine items priced ($0.00 - $999.99) and click page number 2 It gives this url; "/category/slug.html?p=2"

How can I make it so that the link will turn out like this; "/category/slug.html?price=-1000&p=2" ?

Would like to share some code but not quite sure which file I should touch?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the following two files:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Pager.php
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/pager.phtml
```

In the phtml file, it calls `$this->getPageUrl($page)`. You can find this function in your block. Generally, the point of this function is to use your current url (notice the _current) but to replace the page variable with the relevant page (passing in param of page var name to relevant page):

```
public function getPageUrl($page)
{
    return $this->getPagerUrl(array($this->getPageVarName()=>$page));
}
public function getPagerUrl($params=array())
{
    $urlParams = array();
    $urlParams['_current']  = true;
    $urlParams['_escape']   = true;
    $urlParams['_use_rewrite']   = true;
    $urlParams['_query']    = $params;
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/*', $urlParams);
}
```

Obviously, your modified template can cause the location of these functionalities to change, so you'll need to investigate your code base a little for where it's getting cut off.